# Unity DI with MVC 5 in controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I'm currently having issues when trying to make a dependency injection inside a MVC controller.

The current exception is the following:

> The current type, myproject.Core.ToolbarLogic, is an interface and
>   cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Debugging I realized this exception is raised from this sentence (included in a Razor view):

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Toolbar", "Toolbar");  }
```

In the UnityConfig file, all types are registered conveniently, 
I have an empty constructor in the controller, 
the exception is raised from a place I cannot access debugging... Also I have read lots of answers here in StackOverflow and Google, I don't know what to try now (I have tried nearly everything).

Anyone knows what is the problem with the DI?

**Code:**

ToolbarController.cs

```
public class ToolbarController : BaseController
{

    [Dependency]
    public IToolbarLogic ToolbarLogic { get; set; }

    public ToolbarController()
    {
    }


    // GET: Common/Toolbar
    public ActionResult Toolbar()
    {
        bool ShowConfidential = ToolbarLogic.ShowConfidential();
        string linkHome = ToolbarLogic.BindHome(base.User.Identity.Name);
        return PartialView(new ToolbarModel() {
            ShowConfidential = ShowConfidential,
            lnkHome = linkHome
        });
        return PartialView();
    }

}
```

UnityWebActivator.cs

```
/// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.</summary>
public static class UnityWebActivator
{
    /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

        FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
        // Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
    }

    /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
    public static void Shutdown()
    {
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

UnityConfig.cs

```
    /// <summary>
/// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
/// </summary>
public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the configured Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
    /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
    /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
    /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IToolbarLogic, ToolbarLogic>();

        // There is an Unity.config file
        container.LoadConfiguration();
    }
}
```

Unity.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Configuración de Unity -->
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <container>


  </container>
</unity>
```

Edit 1:

I have commented the `LoadConfiguration` line as @Nkosi said, because it makes sense since I don't have any relevant information in my Unity.config (see above, it's empty).

The error stils the same:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MVCControls.Controllers.ToolbarController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, interfaces_logic.Interfaces.IToolbarLogic, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving MVCControls.Controllers.ToolbarController,(none)
  Resolving value for property ToolbarController.ToolbarLogic
  Resolving interfaces_logic.Interfaces.IToolbarLogic,(none)
```

Comment: Can you show the constructor signature of `ToolbarLogic`? I am asking because the error states that `ToolbarLogic` (not `IToolbarLogic`) is an interface.

Comment: @Stefan the constructor signature of `ToolbarLogic` is the following: `public ToolbarLogic() { }` also `ToolbarLogic` is a class: `public class ToolbarLogic`

Comment: Ah, then I misinterpreted it :/

Comment: @Stefan no worries, thanks for helping

Comment: The thing is, this error is typically arises when there is no registration for the given type. Perhaps the config file is overwriting the entry or the `RegisterTypes` or `SetResolver`  is not being called.

Comment: @rpfc, Show the  Unity.config file. Similar to what Stefan suggests I also believe the config is being overwritten. To test this theory switch the two lines in `RegisterTypes` method and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: will you comment the `container.LoadConfiguration();` line. It is used to load from `web.config` file and might be the reason.

Comment: @Mahbubur Rahman I have commented out that line but nothing...

Comment: @Nkosi My unity.config file is pretty empty. Now there is more info in the post, sorry

Comment: As a side note, please don't do DI with properties/attributes. https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the constructor of your controller by the following:

```
public ToolbarController(IToolbarLogic toolbarLogic)
{
    this.ToolbarLogic = toolbarLogic;
}
```

Comment: Although `Unity` provides the `[Dependency]` attribute, I also prefer the DI through the constructor. It's makes your system more DI-framework independent. I am not sure if this is going to help though.

Comment: I have already tried this and the error then is that it needs a parameter-less constructor...

Comment: @rpfc: that message typically occurs when the DI is not configured correctly. Are you sure that `DependencyResolver.SetResolver` is being called?

Comment: @Stefan yes.. its being called

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in your code it is indicated that there is a unity config file.

Calling `container.LoadConfiguration();` after configuration in code will override any matching type registration from the config file.

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container) {
    // Register the default type in code
    container.RegisterType<IToolbarLogic, ToolbarLogic>();

    // Override with the config file, if there is a unity section.
    if (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity") != null) {
        // There is an Unity.config file
        container.LoadConfiguration();
    }        
}
```

Any other type registration survives the loading of the config file if it is not matched with any previous registration in code, if any.

If for example we have the above code and the following config file which contains unity registrations

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <!-- other config removed for brevity -->
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <namespace name="..." />
    <container>
      <register type="IToolbarLogic" />
      <!-- Note the missing mapTo="ToolbarLogic" attribute -->
    </container>
  </unity>
  <!-- other config removed for brevity -->
</configuration>
```

It does not properly map the `IToolbarLogic` interface. If the `LoadConfiguration` extension method is called after registering the interface in code then the previous registration will be overridden and result in the error from the OP.

I suggest you review the .config file and ensure that it has been properly configured. You should also ensure that if `ToolbarLogic` class has any dependencies, that they too are also registered with the container. `ToolbarLogic` should also inherit from `IToolbarLogic`

```
public class ToolbarLogic : IToolbarLogic {
    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Source: [Dependency Injection with Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I checked all your answer and all appears to be as you said... I don't know what it's happening. I have updated info in my post, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

The unity config is missing with the mapto registration entry that it will use to resolve the configuration

```
<container>
  <register type="MyService"> ... </register> <!-- Default registration for type MyService -->
  <register type="ILogger" mapTo="EventLogLogger" /> <!-- type mapping -->
  <register type="ILogger" mapTo="PageAdminLogger" name="emergency" /> <!-- named registration -->
</container>
```

Please use [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx) for more information.

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesn't work either... I think that registering types in the UnityConfig.cs class is enough, like two alternatives to register and map types

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public class ToolbarControllerContext
{
    [Dependency]
    public IToolbarLogic ToolbarLogic { get; set; }
}

public class ToolbarController : BaseController
{    
    private readonly IToolbarLogic _toolbarLogic;

    public ToolbarController(ToolbarControllerContext context)
    {
        _toolbarLogic = context.ToolbarLogic;
    }


    // GET: Common/Toolbar
    public ActionResult Toolbar()
    {
        bool ShowConfidential = _toolbarLogic.ShowConfidential();
        string linkHome = _toolbarLogic.BindHome(base.User.Identity.Name);
        return PartialView(new ToolbarModel() {
            ShowConfidential = ShowConfidential,
            lnkHome = linkHome
        });
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```